# DCEVM remote debuggin

Tags: java, remote-debugging, dcevm

I want to create a development environment in which my java application will run in a virtual machine and the code will be written and managed on the host machine.

The java application inside the virtual machine will use DCEVM because I want to use the enhanced class redefinition while remote debugging the application.

The same version of Java(compatible with DCEVM) will be installed on both virtual machine and host machine.

Is there someone who dealt with a similar setup in the past and who can advise whether this setup is feasible or not ?

I am very interested to know whether the remote debug and enhanced class redefinition will work or not in this setup ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes this will work. You can use DCEVM+HotSwapAgent in the virtual machine and connect to it via your remote debugger in IDE in host machine.

I have worked with a similar setup: Tomcat server + Remote debugging in Eclipse for enhanced class redefinition. They were on the same machine, but the setup and configuration is essentially the same.

Refer https://web.liferay.com/web/enrique.valdes.1/blog/-/blogs/java-classes-instant-reloading-using-dcevm-hotswap-agent for steps on how to set this up. It's the same for a Tomcat server.